# WP Cron based on array list

Tags: wp-cron

I've never used WP Cron in my life and I'm struggling with a task.

I have the following array:

```
$times = array(10:00, 15:00, 21:00);
```

I need to schedule this times so I can call the `enable_update()`

this is the function:

```
function enable_update(){
 $GLOBALS['cron'] = true;
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help!